# The Principal Symbol- Why are those Two Definitions Equivalent?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, differential-operators

This discussion is taken from P. Topping's "Lectures on the Ricci Flow". The author defined the differential operator $L:C^\infty (M) \to C^\infty (M)$ as:
$$ L(u) = a_{ij}\partial_i \partial_j u +b_i \partial_i u + c u $$
It's not written anywhere, but I guess one should sum over $i,j$ in this definition.

The author then presents the concept of a principal symbol of a differential operator as follows:

> Define the *principal symbol* $\sigma(L) : T^*M \to \mathbb{R}$  by:
> $$ \sigma (L) (x,\xi) = a_{ij}(x)\xi_i \xi_j $$
> ...
> An equivalent definition would be the following: Given $(x,\xi)\in T^*M$ and $\phi,f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ smooth with $d\phi(x)=\xi$ define:
> $$
> \sigma (L) (x,\xi)f(x) = \lim_{s\to\infty} s^{-2} e^{-s\phi(x)}L(e^{s\phi}f)(x)
> $$

A proof that:
$$
\lim_{s\to\infty} s^{-2} e^{-s\phi(x)}L(e^{s\phi}f)(x) = a_{ij}(x)\xi_i \xi_j \textbf{f(x)}
$$
Follows. Note the bold trailing $f$.

I can see why those definitions are similar, but it seems like their domains mismatch - The second definition seems to be of type:
$$\sigma(L):T^*M \times C^\infty (M) \to \mathbb{R}$$

Is there a type change of some sort I should be doing to get the equivalence ? Something else perhaps?

Comment: How do you define a differential form e.g. $dx$? one way is by writing all of its components  or by showing how it act on functions. Right?

Comment: Have you tried to compute the limit in the second definition and try to see more precisely how it might be equivalent to the first?

Comment: @C.F.G, I'm probably missing something very obvious here; I'm used to thinking about vector fields as something that acts on the function ring by derivation. I guess you could lower the index of the form and use the vector field action. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Deane, the limit is $a_{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j f(x)$ - it was calculated in the book and specified in the question. If I'm not mistaken, this equals the first definition only for $f=id$. Isn't it?

Comment: @NG_: Def 1: $dx = 1\times dx + 0\times dy + ...$. Def 2: $dx (f) = (df)_x$ for all smooth functions $f$.

Comment: @C.F.G, I don't think I understand Def 2. Specifically, I'm not sure what $dx^i (f) = (df)_{x^i}$ means. $x^i$ is not a point on the manifold (for which $(df)_{p}$ is a covector), nor it is a vector field (for which $df(x)$ may be regarded as a function, I guess).  What am I missing?

Comment: @NG_: it is x-component of $df$. for example $dx(x^2+y^2+1)= (2x,2y)_x = 2x$

Comment: @C.F.G - I think that's the same as lowering the index and acting as the resulting vector field. If the author meant this, shouldn't he write $\sigma (L) f(x)$ instead of $\sigma (L) (x,\xi)f(x)$?

Comment: @NG_: (I thought it is like a differential forms but) principal symbol is like a vector field. it eats a differential forms (not a vector) and gives a real number. So in my opinion it is like,  e.g. $X(2dx-5dy)$. one can use  $X(2dx-5dy)f$ to calculate it. (I am not sure)

Comment: Compare the left side of the first definition to the left side of the second definition

Comment: @C.F.G, indeed, the symbol of a $k$th order PDO is a symmetric contravariant $k$ tensor. Here, using the local coordinate basis $\partial_1, \dots,\partial_n \in T_xM$, the symbol is of the form $$ \sigma(x) = a^{ij}(x)\partial_i\otimes\partial_j $$ and given $\xi =\xi_i\,dx^i$, $$ \sigma(x,\xi) = a^{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j.$$

Comment: In general, if $E$ and $F$ are vector bundles over $M$, then for each $\xi\in T^*_xM$, the symbol is a linear map $$ \sigma(x,\xi): E_x\rightarrow F_x$$ Here, $E$ and $F$ are both the trivial bundle $M\times\mathbb{R}$. Definition 2 defines the symbol as such a map.

Comment: Hi @Deane, thanks for you reply. Using the notation of your second to last comment; I see why $$ \sigma(x)(f) $$ is meaningful, but fail to see why $$ \sigma(x,\xi)(f) $$ is meaningful.  Would you be kind enough to spell it out for me?

Comment: $\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$ My notation for $\sigma(x)$ is confusing, because $\partial_i$ does *not* mean the partial differential operator. It is instead an element of $T_xM$ and $\partial_i\otimes\partial_j \in T_xM\otimes T_xM$. In particular, $\sigma(x)$ is a bilinear function \begin{align*} \sigma(x): T^*_M &\rightarrow \R\\ \xi_i\,dx^i &\mapsto a^{ij}(x)\xi_i\xi_j. \end{align*} So $\sigma(x)f$ does not make sense. What does make sense is $(\sigma(x)(\xi))f(x).$ We, however, write this as $\sigma(x,\xi)f(x),$ where the scalar $\sigma(x,\xi)$ is being *multiplied* by the scalar $f(x)$.